# How to draw a dashed line using CGContext / CGContextRef? Why is my code producing a solid line?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, xamarin.ios

This is Xamarin.iOS code but I presume the native folks can spot the problem too, so I tagged it also ObjC.

I'm subclassing UIView and "abuse" it to draw a dashed line from the view's X, Y to the view's right, bottom bounds.

The color I set is *white*. The line style is supposed to be *dashed*. However I get a *black*, *solid* line. What am I doing wrong here?

```
public override void Draw (RectangleF rect)
{
    using (CGContext g = UIGraphics.GetCurrentContext ())
    {
        g.SetLineWidth (1f);
    g.SetLineDash (0, new float[] { 10f, 4f });

        g.MoveTo (rect.X, rect.Y);
        g.AddLineToPoint (rect.Right, rect.Bottom);
        g.SetStrokeColor (this.color.CGColor);
        g.StrokePath ();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As so often the answer becomes obvious once you post the question here :-)

This line is causing the problem:

```
g.SetLineDash (0, new float[] { 10f, 4f });
```

It has to be:

```
g.SetLineDash (0, new float[] { 10f, 4f }, 2);
```

From Apple's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGContext/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000950-CH1g-F17053):

> If the lengths parameter specifies an array, pass the number of
>   elements in the array. Otherwise, pass 0.